# Create a dropdown menu from HTML headers and paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Since I'm completely new to JavaScript and JQuery, I have some problems creating dropdown menus starting from a HTML document structured in this way:

```
<h2>Type 1</h2>
<h3>Model 1</h3>
<a href="....">link 1</a>
<a href="....">link 2</a>
<a href="....">link 3</a>
<h3>Model 2</h3>
<a href="....">link 1</a>
<a href="....">link 2</a>
<h2>Type 2</h2>
<h3>Model 1</h3>
<a href="....">link 1</a>
<h3>Model 2</h3>
<a href="....">link 1</a>
<a href="....">link 2</a>
<a href="....">link 3</a>
```

and so on.

What I want is a first dropdown menu which shows my types, and a second one in which, after a type is selected, the models appear. When the model is selected too, the links should appear below the dropdown menus (also a third dropdown menu with the link texts and a "go" button is OK).

It should be simple but I can't get to it! I've tried different ways but nothing :-(.

Anyone has hint for me?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

@Zapp: am I missing something or the code should be so?

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Type 1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>Model 1</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="....">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="....">link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="....">link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Model 2</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="....">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="....">link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Type 2</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>Model 1</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="....">link 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Model 2</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="....">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="....">link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="....">link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Anyway, thanks for all the help you are giving me! I'm near the result I want :)

Comment: Is there a reason youre not doing it with .css? If not, you can put everything in <ul> and <li> tags. And with .css you will use pseudos to do the hovers dropdown affect.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I can wrap all in <ul> and <li> but how? There should be an ul in a li (for the model)? And then is it possible, with css, style 2 different dropdown menus from my HTML code?

Comment: Also, w3schools.com is a great place to browse if your learning/building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic structure. Copy it and try it. Then modify it to what you need:

```html
<style>

li {list-style:none;}

ul li ul li { display:none; }
ul li:hover ul li {display:block; }
</style>

<ul>
<li><h2>Type 1</h2></li>
<li><h3>Model 1</h3></li>
<li><a href="....">link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="....">link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="....">link 3</a></li>
<li><h3>Model 2</h3></li>
<li><a href="....">link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="....">link 2</a></li>
<li><ul><h2>Type 2</h2></li>
<li><h3>Model 1</h3></li>
<li><a href="....">link 1</a></li>
<li><h3>Model 2</h3></li>
<li><a href="....">link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="....">link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="....">link 3</a></ul></li>
</ul>
```